# Rascal syntax error in if statement (newbie q)

Tags: if-statement, rascal

What's wrong with the following?

I'm getting a syntax error on the last line, just after the if

**Module mytest**

```
int n = if (3 > 2) 1; else 0;
```

thx,
--Dennis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top-level declarations in Rascal (which include declarations in the console) expect an expression on the right-hand side, so you would need to instead say:

```
int n = ( 3 > 2 ) ? 1 : 0;
```

If you are inside a function, there is an inconsistency in what is allowed, so this should work fine:

```
n = if (3 > 2) 1; else 0;
```

but what you have above also won't work in that context.